# C# Using Ajax To Get Data From Backend Once Signed Into Azure AD

Tags: c#, ajax, azure

I'm building an application using [asp .net core 3.1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/?view=aspnetcore-3.1)
with [Azure Single Sign On](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/what-is-single-sign-on) feature.
My issue is when I deploy the application on the Azure, I can sign in no worries, however when I use [Ajax](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) to talk to the back end (Controller) to pull data to popular the fields that are required, I get this error `Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?cl`
From what I can understand from the research I have done, this is a feature that was created to help prevent getting maliciously hijacked and was introduced by the World Wide Web Consortium.
It looks like it trying to get reauthorized from Azure when I have already signed in which leads me to believe Ajax doesnt pass the cookies or token from the browser.
Here is the function from the .cshtml file

```
function GetPageSize() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'path=' + $('#jobTypeId').val(),
        data: $('#myform').serialize(),
        success: function (data) {
           // Does Stuff
        },
        error: function (data) {
           // Does Other Stuff
        },
    });
}
```

And here is part of the controller.

```
[Authorize]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;
    private readonly IWebHostEnvironment _env;

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="logger"></param>
    public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _env = env;
    }

    public IActionResult Index() => View();

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    [Route("Home/Path/{str?}")]
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult GetFunc()([FromQuery] string str)
    {
        using (ApiHelper apiHelper= new ApiHelper (Startup.Configuration.GetSection("ConnectionString")["connectionString"]))
        {
            // Do Some Stuff And Return Json
        }
    }
 }
```

And here Is the ApiHelper (I dont think this is irrelevant however here it is)

```
 /// <summary>
/// 
/// </summary>
public class ApiHelper : IDisposable
{
    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    public LockString ConnectionString { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="connectionString"></param>
    public ApiHelper(string connectionString) => ConnectionString = new LockString(connectionString);

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public IEnumerable<MyType> Func()
    {
        // Connect to sql
        // Return results.            
    }
```

I tried adding

```
services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddDefaultPolicy(
                builder =>
                {
                    builder.AllowAnyOrigin();
                    builder.AllowAnyMethod();
                    builder.AllowAnyOrigin();
                    builder.AllowAnyHeader();
                });
        });
```

in `ConfigureServices` and `app.UseCors();` in configure (I didnt have UseMVC, so I added it above `app.UseHttpsRefirection()` however I still get the same error mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this kind to bring JSON file from controller that using [HttpPost]

```
 function GetPageSize() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/Home/test',
            data: JSON.stringify(),
            contentType: "application/json",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
               // Does Stuff
            },
            error: function (data) {
               // Does Other Stuff
            },
        });
    }
```

and this is the controller and the function :

```
[Authorize]
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
    public JsonResult test()
    {

            SqlSelect ="any query it's just an example";

        string result = SqlRequest(SqlSelect);



        //Source data returned as JSON    
        return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

hope that's help you some how.

Comment: Is your application using an Azure AD SSO?

Comment: I'll add the changes to the Ajax and see how it goes.

Comment: unfortunately no change, thanks for your suggestion however.

Comment: I noticed that this works on the home page, however when I go to another page, that is when it fails, any ideas?

Comment: what do you mean when you go to another page? I'm sorry just give me an example so we can work together.